# Create a new list of strings using another but without duplicates

Tags: java, list

I've looked at multiple different answer and questions but none seem to be giving the result I would like. my issue is that I have a .txt file with 426458 states (disregarding the rules) of noughts and crosses with the format shown below.

```
[E][E][E]
[E][E][E]
[E][E][E]

[X][X][X]
[O][O][O]
[E][E][E]
```

I load the file using this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("src/AllPlayerOneStates.txt"));
    sc.useDelimiter("\r");
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
      lines.add(sc.next());
    }
```

This creates a list with every element being a state then I would like to create a new list without duplicate states.

I've tried using StringBuilder to simply output all the unique states but it gives me a number much less than expected aswell as looping through each element and comparing it to all the rest but I may have done it wrong as it told me the amount of unique states was larger than 426458. I'm relatively new to programming.

Comment: "This creates an array ..." The code you show does not use arrays at all.

Comment: sorry about that, I thought they were a similar concept

Comment: They are similar, in some ways. But "array" is a specific thing, and your code doesn't use that specific thing. Words matter, especially words with exact definitions in the JLS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Set` instead of `List` and it will remove the duplicates itself, e.g.:

```
Set<String> lines = new HashSet<String>();
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
  lines.add(sc.next());
}
```

Once this `while` loop finishes, `lines.size()` will give you number of unique rules.

If you want to preserve the order, you can use `LinkedHashSet` instead of `HashSet`.

Comment: it must be the way im formatting my text file as it gives me the same result of only 28 unique states when there should be much more

Comment: try printing out each element as it gets added into the set, that might give you more idea on what's being added..

Comment: You will only get the right result if `equals` and `hashCode` correctly compare states. Does one line of input really correspond to a single state?

Comment: this is what the hash list looks like after being read into a file http://pastebin.com/4rEACmqS im not entirely sure what is going wrong or why the 3rd or 4th element is not in the same format

Answer (score 3):

> This creates an array with every element being a state then I would
>   like to create a new array without duplicate states.

Try the following way:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(lines);
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(set);
```

Here `newList` is your new List of states that doesn't contain duplicates.